# In the Walking Dead, why did some people not turn after being infected?

Tags: the-walking-dead

The airborne zombie-virus outbreak happens. Lots of people turn without being bit; other people don't. Do they ever explain why?

Comment: As far as the series goes, I think to remember that you have to die, in order to turn. As long as you stay alive, you wont turn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Walker bites in the Walking Dead fatal?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/why-are-walker-bites-in-the-walking-dead-fatal)

Comment: See also: [In Walking Dead (TV), is it possible that a survivor becomes immune](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/in-walking-dead-tv-is-it-possible-that-a-survivor-becomes-immune) and [Why hasn't Michonne turned in The Walking Dead?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27058/5184)

Comment: @bitmask I remember seeing a comment from the creator; he remarked that most of the Zombies in the Atlanta scene weren't bit. There were a lot of (non-elderly) Zombies in that scene - they couldn't have all died from other causes during the outbreak, and they weren't all bit - so they must have turned some other way.

Comment: And [Walking Dead season 2, what did people in the parked cars die from anyway?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8857/5184) and [In Walking Dead Season 3, how did the guys in riot gear die?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26991/5184).

Comment: @phantom42 I'm trying to figure out how so many turned without being bit. I understand why zombie bites are fatal.

Comment: @hal, Bites are not required to turn. Death with no brain injury is the only thing required to turn. Bites are more likely to cause death due to bacterial infection.

Comment: @Phantom42 how do you account for hundreds of thousands of intact dead people in Atlanta?

Comment: @hal, if you're referring to the highway scene, look at the question about the parked cars I linked above.

Comment: @phantom42 no I'm not referring to the highway scene. I'm referring to the scene where Rick gets mobbed in the tank. Your link provides these answers: 1) Severe brain trauma from car crash pileup.
2) Another brain damage that killed them.
3) Already zombies that got killed somehow.   1) there's no car pileup, so 1) is out.  2) That wouldn't explain how an entire metropolitan population (or an unlikely significantly large portion of it) was brain damaged in just a few weeks. The zombies were intact so 3) is out. So those answers dont work for Atlanta.

Comment: We see walkers all the time without immediately obvious wounds. The fact that you can't see the wounds of every walker in a swarm/mob doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @phantom42 the creator remarked that most of the zombies in Atlanta didn't have bites.

Comment: He's talking about the pileup in the cars.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13444/discussion-between-phantom42-and-hal)

Comment: @phantom42 you know everything he said? The comment was about the tank scene.

Comment: The quote from Kirkman about people being non-walkers was from [here](http://blogs.amctv.com/the-walking-dead/2012/03/glen-mazzara-faqs/). He's talking about the pileup.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm not disputing that you read what you read somewhere. I said that I read a different quote, which is not incompatible with what you read.

Comment: @Hal Please add that quote to the question, and flesh out the question so it's clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

> It can be assumed, however, that an undetermined number of original "outbreak" cases involved recently-reanimated zombies that were relatively intact and "clean". This could indicate that the active form of the virus does in fact play a part in the attack on the victim's system, perhaps by rapidly wiping out immunity cells which would allow for even weak infections to be deadly.

From http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Zombies

Answer (score 1):

It has not been explained how and why the virus exist yet. The only thing we know is that everyone is infected. This means  that it doesn't matter if you are bitten or not. As long as you die, you will turn in a zombie. The people that have turned have died, one way or the other. So far, we haven't seen any alive person to turn.

Rick's speech at Vol. 05: The Best Defense perfectly sums it up:

> The second we put a bullet in the head of one of those undead
>   monsters -- the moment one of us drove a hammer into one of their
>   faces -- or cut a head off. We became what we are! And that's just it.
>   THAT's what it comes down to. You people don't know what we are.
>
> We're surrounded by the DEAD. We're among them -- and **when we finally
>   give up we become them**! We're living on borrowed time here. Every
>   minute of our life is a minute we steal from them! You see them out
>   there. You KNOW that when we die -- we become them. You think we hide
>   behind walls to protect us from the walking dead?
>
> Don't you get it? We ARE the walking dead! WE are the walking dead.

Comment: -1 | Does not address the question.

Comment: 'Lots of people turn without being bit; other people don't.' and I answer 'The only thing we know is that everyone is infected'

Comment: Does this not address the question?

Comment: You only give evidence for "everyone's infected" but that's not in question. The question asks, "does this infection imply you can turn spontaneously without being bit or killed otherwise".

Comment: And I said 'This means that it doesn't matter if you are bitten or not. As long as you die, you will turn in a zombie. [...] So far, we haven't seen any alive person to turn.'